# Spring DisposableBean does not work

Tags: spring, tomcat

I am implementing the DisposableBean in one of my beans to get notified when my server is shutting down. However, the destroy method is never called.

I am running Tomcat with Spring 3.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ContextLoaderListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) and override `contextDestroyed` method.

Don't forget to declare `ContextLoaderListener` in your `web.xml`.

Comment: If it works, you might want to consider accepting this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sure :) One last thing, why does spring not do it for me? Does the DisposableBean only work under special circumstances?

Comment: I guess (don't know for sure) when Tomcat goes down it simply terminates all the threads, and Spring is not that intrusive to hold the threads and perform graceful shutdowns. I would guess DisposableBean only works in controlled environments where you have full control of the BF lifecycle. Context listener OTOH is a standard hook in Tomcat so this is a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: Actually I tried your solution. I can easily get the Root Context, but what I will need are the servlet/application contexts. how do I get access to these?

Comment: You need to place Spring's `ContextLoaderListener` in web.xml of the webapp you need context for. Or, if what you are doing isn't Spring-specific, you can just use standard ServletContextListener, http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html - Spring's listener doesn't do much more than this does. Alternatively, bind all necessary objects in JNDI (e.g. upon webapp startup) and access these whenever necessary.

Comment: Sure, I am using the subclassed Listener in the web.xml. But I am only getting the root context of the beans defined in applicationContext.xml, not the ones from application-servlet.xml and the imported files.

Comment: I think it's best if you create another question and provide more details on what's in your applicationContext.xml, application-servlet.xml and "imported files", mentioning the what exactly are you loading from which webapp/spring context.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ApplicationContext, use AbstractApplicationContext.
Then register the same. Spring wont call DisposableBean for desktop application if you are using  ApplicationContext.

Ex:
AbstractApplicationContext appCxt= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    appCxt.registerShutdownHook();

Answer (score 0):

I tried this option.

With `obj` object with `destroy()` method, add this:

> Runtime.getRuntime ( ).addShutdownHook (  new Thread ( obj::destroy ) );